# React-router issues with including express

Tags: reactjs, express

I have set up react for frontend, and for my backend i'm using express.
I came cross with this github [repo](https://github.com/crsandeep/simple-react-full-stack) which is implements to be "simple react-express fullstack" So I went ahead and forked the repo, filled up with my own stuff.

I have sign-in/sign-up form at frontend, which accordingly redirects to /auth/sign-up or /auth/sign-in with using the react router like this.

```
     <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Signin}/>
              <Route path="/auth/sign-in" component={Signin}/>
              <Route path="/auth/sign-up" component={Signup}/>
    </Switch>
```

When I try to visit these paths when running standalone the frontend, it works. But if I run it with express, the path(s) say error 404, any ideas? Should it be acting like that? My github repo could be found [here](https://github.com/mikk-io/2)

Answer (score 0):

You should make two separately applications. I sugest  you to use create-react-app for frontend app, and expressjs as backend app. Then in the your react app, in package.json you must add url to your server app. For example: "proxy":"localhost:3000".